# Issues with UseWindowsService

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

Added .UseWindowsService to our startup code, and although we can install the binary as a service via “sc” when we try to start the service we get an error that the service has not responded.

I’ve seen examples where “main” was switched to an async Task function, which seems to resolve the issue, but I’ve also seen many examples for running a .Net core API app as a service where main is a simple void function.

Our start up code doesnt do anything other than set up logging, so I’m not sure what the issue is.

Any ideas on why we would need to run the service as async? Thoughts on how to debug?

Comment: Sorry I thought I had the answer but turns out I had just confused myself hehe. I am running a similar setup it sounds like, and had a similar error, but was able to get mine working using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices + .UseWindowsService(). I am running with dotnet 5. It sounds like this functionality has been changed somewhat in dotnet 6.

Comment: I'm building this type of application and ran into a few challenges too.  Like the OP states the service could register with sc.exe create "FTP Download" binpath="C:\FTP\FTPGet.exe" but did not start. Turns out I needed to add to the IHOST.CreateDefaultBuilder()  needed  .UseWindowsService(option => options.ServiceName = "FTP Download"; })  And now I can start the service.

Comment: Seems the useWindowsService method never gets called. Currently trying to figure out why.